# Pandas to mark rows fit conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have a simple dataset, and I want to mark the rows with below conditions, if:

- both the columns Close and End are older than today
- and, column Stage in [One, Two, Three]
- and, column Project Number is not blank

I came up with below lines, but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO


csvfile = StringIO("""
ID  Stage   Close   Project Number  End"
A899    One 26/08/2019  KL1468  30/08/2019"
A572    Two 31/12/2020  KL1493  17/12/2019"
A778    Three   26/08/2019      16/08/2019"
A704    Four    31/12/2020  KL1036  01/12/2019"
A650    One 31/12/2020  KL1522  23/12/2019"
A830    Two 31/08/2021  KL1535  03/08/2021"
A669    Three   18/08/2021  KL1536  03/08/2021"
A892    Four    31/08/2021  KL1534  03/08/2021"
A789    One 31/05/2021  KL1537  04/08/2021"
A821    Two 31/12/2020  KL1578  03/11/2019"
A992    Three   29/07/2019  KL1609  26/06/2019"
A550    Four    31/12/2020  KL1243  30/11/2019"
A707    One 31/12/2020  KL1523  29/11/2019"
A740                
A917    Three   31/07/2021  KL1072  29/07/2021"
A627    Four    30/06/2021  KL1577  15/06/2021"

""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

def condition_1(s):
    if (df['Project Number'].any() and s['Expiry_1'] < datetime.datetime.now() and s['Close_1'] < datetime.datetime.now() and np.where(df['Stage'].isin(['One','Two','Three']))):
        return "Overdue"
    else:
        return ''

df['Expiry_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'].str[3:5] + '/' + df['End'].str[:2] + '/' + df['End'].str[-4:])
df['Close_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close'].str[3:5] + '/' + df['Close'].str[:2] + '/' + df['Close'].str[-4:])
df["Overdue Project"] = df.apply(condition_1, axis=1)

df.to_excel("c:\\Projects\\output.xlsx", index = False)
```

What went wrong, and what's the right way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format parameter:

```
df['Expiry_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Close_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

then test if less by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) or greater by
[`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) both columns and it need test if both are `True`s use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for first mask `m1`, for second use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and for last [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html), last chain them by `&` for bitwise `AND` and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df[['Expiry_1','Close_1']].lt(pd.to_datetime('now')).all(axis=1)
m2 = df['Stage'].isin(['One','Two','Three'])
m3 = df['Project Number'].notna()

df['Overdue Project'] = np.where(m1 & m2 & m3,  "Overdue", '')
```

---

```
print (df)
      ID  Stage       Close Project Number         End   Expiry_1    Close_1  \
0   A899    One  26/08/2019         KL1468  30/08/2019 2019-08-30 2019-08-26   
1   A572    Two  31/12/2020         KL1493  17/12/2019 2019-12-17 2020-12-31   
2   A778  Three  26/08/2019            NaN  16/08/2019 2019-08-16 2019-08-26   
3   A704   Four  31/12/2020         KL1036  01/12/2019 2019-12-01 2020-12-31   
4   A650    One  31/12/2020         KL1522  23/12/2019 2019-12-23 2020-12-31   
5   A830    Two  31/08/2021         KL1535  03/08/2021 2021-08-03 2021-08-31   
6   A669  Three  18/08/2021         KL1536  03/08/2021 2021-08-03 2021-08-18   
7   A892   Four  31/08/2021         KL1534  03/08/2021 2021-08-03 2021-08-31   
8   A789    One  31/05/2021         KL1537  04/08/2021 2021-08-04 2021-05-31   
9   A821    Two  31/12/2020         KL1578  03/11/2019 2019-11-03 2020-12-31   
10  A992  Three  29/07/2019         KL1609  26/06/2019 2019-06-26 2019-07-29   
11  A550   Four  31/12/2020         KL1243  30/11/2019 2019-11-30 2020-12-31   
12  A707    One  31/12/2020         KL1523  29/11/2019 2019-11-29 2020-12-31   
13  A740    NaN         NaN            NaN         NaN        NaT        NaT   
14  A917  Three  31/07/2021         KL1072  29/07/2021 2021-07-29 2021-07-31   
15  A627   Four  30/06/2021         KL1577  15/06/2021 2021-06-15 2021-06-30   

   Overdue Project  
0          Overdue  
1          Overdue  
2                   
3                   
4          Overdue  
5                   
6                   
7                   
8                   
9          Overdue  
10         Overdue  
11                  
12         Overdue  
13                  
14                  
15
```